# Store series of captured images into array

Tags: ios, swift

In the function below(didPressTakePhoto), I am trying to take a series of pictures(10 in this case), store them into an array and display them as an animation in the "gif". Yet the program keeps crashing and I have no idea why. This is all after one button click, hence the function name. Also, I tried taking the animation code outside the for loop, but the imageArray would then lose it's value for some reason.

```
func didPressTakePhoto(){

    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput?.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo){
        videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.Portrait
        stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection, completionHandler: {
            (sampleBuffer, error) in

            //var counter = 0
            if sampleBuffer != nil {

                for var index = 0; index < 10; ++index {

                    let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                    let dataProvider  = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(imageData)
                    let cgImageRef = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dataProvider, nil, true, CGColorRenderingIntent.RenderingIntentDefault)
                    var imageArray: [UIImage] = []
                    let image = UIImage(CGImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.Right)

                    imageArray.append(image)
                    imageArray.insert(image, atIndex: index++)

                    self.tempImageView.image = image
                    self.tempImageView.hidden = false


                    //UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)

                    var gif: UIImageView!
                    gif.animationImages = imageArray

                    gif.animationRepeatCount = -1
                    gif.animationDuration = 1
                    gif.startAnimating()

                }

            }


        })
    }


}
```

Comment: What is the crash? Which line?

Answer (score 0):

Never try to make an array of images (i.e., a `[UIImage]` as you are doing). A UIImage is very big, so an *array* of *many* images is *huge* and you will run out of memory and crash.

- Save your images to disk, maintaining only *references* to them (i.e. an array of their names).
- Before using your images in the interface, reduce them to the actual physical size you will need for that interface. Using a full-size image for a mere screen-sized display (or smaller) is a huge waste of energy. You can use the ImageIO framework to get a "thumbnail" smaller version of the image from disk without wasting memory.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new [UIImage] in every iteration of the loop, so in the last iteration there's only one image, you should take the imageArray creation out of the loop. Having said that, you should take into account what @matt answered